# mysqli cannot insert and update query into mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Please find my code below:

```
<?php
        //Insert New User to Database
        $username = "root";
        $password = "root";
        $hostname = "localhost";
        $db = "ab-cargo";
        $conn = mysqli_connect($hostname, $username, $password, $db);

        if (mysqli_connect_errno()){
            echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
        }

        $user_id = $_SESSION['namechat'];
        $user_email = $_SESSION['emailchat'];
        $last_login = $datetime_formatted;

        mysqli_query($conn,"INSERT INTO users (`user_id`, `user_email`, last_login, isActive) VALUES ('".$user_id."', '".$user_email."', '".$last_login."', 1)");
        mysqli_query($conn,"UPDATE users SET last_login = ".$last_login.", isActive = 1 WHERE `user_email` = ".$user_email."");

    ?>
```

Please help me to find what's wrong with mysqli_query because it won't update and insert the data in my database, even though the connection is finely working (I know it because user is able to login).

**Edit:** Query insert is to input new user data into the database and if the user data is already in the database before, the update query will update last_login time/date only.

Comment: You started the session? You are open to SQL injections. Why `insert` then `update`? Check that status of each query execution.

Comment: Just a tip, you don't need to concatenate the variables, you can just write them into the string.

Comment: Use prepared statements. Some thin in your data is probably causing this and as @chris85 pointed out you are open to sql injection.

Comment: This question has nothing to do with phpmyadmin which is a web based client to the **mysql** database

Comment: Your update syntax is incorrect. You have unquoted strings. Also `user_id` is not auto incrementing?

Comment: Instead of editing the question why not use the comments? Anyway per your update there is no check for which query to execute so both queries execute. What is failing?

Comment: Ah yes... I've made a mistake in above code. Based on @panda's answer. I know I have to use mysqli_real_escape_string to prevent MySQL injection.

Comment: @TricksfortheWeb yes. concatenate the variables is also my mistake as well. Thank you for figuring it out. Oh also, user_id is not auto incrementing. Thank you for your help, all.

Comment: To auto-increment, just set the mysql to autoincrement using phpmyadmin, and then make that `NULL`, instead of sending a variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to prevent MySQL injection with `mysqli_real_escape_string`. Read up more about this function [here](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php).

Use `or die mysqli_error($conn)` to check for errors in query.

Also, check if each query is successful before proceeding to the next one.

```
$user_id = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_SESSION['namechat']);
$user_email = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_SESSION['emailchat']);
$last_login = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $datetime_formatted);

$query1 = mysqli_query($conn,"INSERT INTO users (`user_id`, `user_email`, last_login, isActive) VALUES ('$user_id', '$user_email', '$last_login', 1)") or die mysqli_error($conn);

if ($query1) $success = 1;

if ($success) $query2 = mysqli_query($conn,"UPDATE users SET last_login = '$last_login', isActive = 1 WHERE `user_email` = '$user_email'");

if ($query2) echo 'User added';
```

Comment: thank you so much for your help.

Comment: @anakpanti You're welcome! :P

Answer (score 0):

```
$_SESSION['namechat']= "1";     
    $_SESSION['emailchat']= "example@gmail.com";
    //SET DATE TIME ZONE
    date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Calcutta");
    $datetime_formatted = date("h:i:sa");


    $user_id = $_SESSION['namechat'];
    $user_email = $_SESSION['emailchat'];
    $last_login = $datetime_formatted;

    //HERE INSERT THE DATA INTO USER
    $sql = "INSERT INTO users (user_id, user_email, last_login, isActive) VALUES ('$user_id', '$user_email', '$last_login', '1')";

    if(mysqli_query($conn,$sql)){
        echo "sql inserted successfully";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "failed to insert".$sql."<br>".mysqli_error($conn);
    } 


    //HERE UPDATE THE DATA INTO USER
    $sql_up ="UPDATE users SET last_login ='$last_login', isActive = '1' WHERE user_email = '$user_email'";

    if(mysqli_query($conn, $sql_up)){
        echo "Data Updated";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Failed to Updated the data".$sql_up."<br>".mysqli_error($conn);
    }
```